"Unauthorized: No token provided")
Hi I just have this small problem i'm trying to create a workout website that basically nothing or needs is meant to work until the user authenticated yeah so l've l've created everything. l've done everything but every time I click add new workout just like not talking or unauthorized no token provided I just need help with fixing that error

It is an error in your code, somewhere. Check line 37
